# How to use a Post deployment script to bulk insert a CSV on remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am using a post deployment script in my SQL server database project to bulk insert data. This works great if I publish to a local database, but if I publish to a remote database, obvisouly the CSV I am bulk inserting from, will not exists on the remote server. I have considered using a command line copy on the CSV to a shared folder, but this raises security concerns, as anyone with access to this folder could possibly tamper with a deployment.

How should I be using post deployment scripts to copy data to a remote server? A CSV is easier to maintian than a bunch of inserts, so I would prefer using a CSV. Has anyone ran into and solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is the one you mentioned. Command line copy it to a **secured** shared folder and  BCP from there.

From that point on the security of the folder depends on network services.